# Custom Exceptions: Differentiate via many subclasses or single class backed with enum?

Tags: java, exception, custom-exceptions

I'm looking to implement my own set of `Exceptions` for a projects I am currently working on. The project relies on a core framework with a base framework exception `MyFrameworkException` (I am also writing this framework).

For any given project I would like to throw several different types of `Exceptions` and I can't decide between using multiple subclasses or a single subclass with some form of an `Enum` as a constructor parameter.

In both cases I have:

```
public class MyFrameworkException   extends Exception              { /*...*/ }
```

***Option 1:***

```
public class MyProjectBaseException extends MyFrameworkException   { /*...*/ }
public class SpecificExceptionType1 extends MyProjectBaseException { /*...*/ }
public class SpecificExceptionType1 extends MyProjectBaseException { /*...*/ }
public class SpecificExceptionType1 extends MyProjectBaseException { /*...*/ }
```

Then, throughout the project I would throw the specific exception for any problem that occurs.

***Option 2:***

```
public class MyProjectException extends MyFrameworkException {
  public static enum Type {
    SpecificType1, SpecificType2, SpecificType3
  }
  public MyProjectException( Type type ) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Here I would always throw `MyProjectException` with the specific enum type for any problem that occurs. I'd provide some mechanism so that a switch statement could be performed on any `MyProjectException` based on the type enum.

**What's the best way to handle exceptions in projects, especially those sharing a common infrastructure?** Are the two options above good solutions? Why or why not? And what are any better solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chief disadvantage to Option 2 (a common exception + enum) is that you lose some of the utility of checked exceptions. A method pretty much has to say simply "something framework-related might go wrong":

```
public void foo()
throws MyFrameworkException
```

...rather than "x or y might go wrong":

```
public void foo()
throws SomethingWentWrongException, SomethingElseWentWrongException
```

It means a function that may need to handle one framework exception has to be prepared to handle *any* of them, whereas if you're specific, a function need only be prepared to handle the exceptions that are thrown by the framework methods it calls.

So for me, a hierarchy such as Option 1 (it needn't be quite so flat, if a structure suggests itself) is the way to go. That said, there are people who don't like checked exceptions at all, and for them I suspect the above is not a compelling argument. :-)

**Edit** And picking up duffymo's point: I've assumed you were talking about exceptions you really did have to create. Absolutely throw *standard* exceptions wherever it makes sense (which is nearly everywhere). Don't create your own `MyFrameworkIllegalArgumentException`, for instance, just use `IllegalArgumentException` (or its various subclasses).

Comment: To add to this: Option 2 look like error codes disguised as exceptions.

Comment: Yes, the plan is to never rethrow exceptions in new wrapped exceptions and also to allow certain java/third-party-lib exceptions to be propagated outside of my project methods. So many of my methods will throw custom exceptions + other java exceptions.

Comment: @Andy: Excellent, yeah, I figured you probably meant that.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with exceptions extending java.lang.RuntimeException with descriptive class names.

If you have so many business-specific exceptions that this becomes oppressive, it means you're probably doing it wrong.

See Joshua Bloch's advice about [favoring standard exceptions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/toc.html).

Comment: `java.lang.Runnable`? Did you mean `RuntimeException`?

Comment: Yes, I did.  Going too fast; distracted.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't inherit from a generic `MyFrameworkException`, as long as you dont provide any functionality in there common to all projects. Else, always extend Exception.

Normally you should throw meaningful exceptions at domain/layer boundaries. So regarding your question, you should go with option 1, having in mind the point above. Option 2 would increase code complexity, as you will always have to check for the exception type to determine what went wrong. Let the exception class speak for itself.

Comment: MyFrameworkException would have some basic functionality and would allow me to identify/group exceptions that originate from the whole suite of code, so I still kinda want to use it as a base.

Comment: I would agree with Andy - I see little or no good reason to extend anything other than the java.lang base classes.